# How to convert to date-fns?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

I have following `moment` expression:

```
<DialogContent>
  {startDate ? (
    <DateTimePicker
      value={startDate}
      onChange={(value: any) =>
        setStartDate(moment(value).format())
```

I would like to convert to `date-fns` format, but it fails, it is always 1970 something, why? I converted like this:

```
setStartDate(getUnixTime(new Date(value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import `format` function from `date-fns` and use it:

```js
import { format } from 'date-fns';

// Pass desired format as a second parameter
setStartDate(format(value, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`moment(value).format()` return a ISO 8601 date string, look like: `2021-11-10T10:19:09+09:00`. Then, I guess the `setStartDate` function require a date string with ISO 8601 format.

The goal is using `date-fns` to create a string as the result of `moment.format`.

To do that, you need to create a date object. If it works with `moment(value)` syntax, mean `value` is a millisecond timestamp number (`1636507295498`) or a formal date string (`2021-11-10`). Then you can create a date object by Date constructor:

```
new Date(value);
```

Now, you can use [formatISO](https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/formatISO) to create the required date string:

```
formatISO(dateObject);
```

The final look will be like this:

```
setStartDate(formatISO(new Date(value)))
```